# How to save data members of Fragment during configuration change?

Tags: android

I have a fragment that creates an `AsyncTask` to download and parse a RSS feed, then displays it in a list. The problem is, downloaded feed is stored in a `RSSFeed`object, and that becomes null when the fragment is recreated after a screen rotation. That means every time the user rotates the screen, the app must re-download the feed, wasting time and bandwidth. I could have it load a cached copy of the xml but that still takes time and is bad UX.

Up until now I've been using `setRetainInstance(true)` in the fragment, and it seems to work. However, I've recently read that it is not recommended to use `setRetainInstance(true`) in a fragment with a UI, something about leaking context. I've also seen other people say that it's ok and even recommended, as long as you reassign a value to views once the activity is recreated. I'm not sure how accurate either answer is, some help here would be appreciated.

Assuming I don't use `setRetainInstance(true)`, and the fragment is recreated on configuration change, I'd like a way to preserve just that object. If it was a string or int I know to use onSaveInstanceState and a bundle, but the thing is this feed isn't serializable, nor is it recommended to serialize and deserialize a potentially large object. So the second question is, what can I do to preserve the feed so I don't have to reload it again?

Comment: You can make array parcelable

Comment: Create a separate fragment without UI with setRetainInstance(true) and  call AsyncTask from it?

Comment: After reading up on parcelable it seems that it is not ideal. The feed object is not just string, there are other objects - not mine - in there too. Making everything parcelable would be very difficult, if not impossible.

@blyabtroi I'll give this a try as well.